# Django - Attachment garbage collection

Tags: django

I have created a model which attaches media to blog posts:

```
class MediaAttachment(models.Model):
    media = models.ForeignKey(Media, related_name='attachment')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_index=True)
    object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

It works well, but when if I attach some media to a blog entry and then delete that blog entry, the attachment to that entry remains in the MediaAttachment table. What would be the smartest way to GC the MediaAttachment tables? Is signals the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to make this work nicely using the following method.

I added this signal to my MediaAttachment model:

```
post_delete.connect(MediaAttachment.objects.delete_attachment)
```

Then my delete method looks like this:

```
def delete_attachment(self, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    ctype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance)
    return self.filter(content_type=ctype, object_id=instance.pk).delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

Signals?  No.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/instances/#deleting-objects

Just add a `delete` method to "cascade" the delete to related objects.

Comment: My issue with this is that I have to overwrite the delete method in my Blog model to delete the entries in the MediaAttachment model... I'd much rather keep all logic related to MediaAttachment and it's tables in the MediaAttachment model itself. Ideally, the Blog model wouldn't reference MediaAttachment at all and act independently.